# React Native - How to add opacity feedback to Pressable component?

Tags: react-native

The new `Pressable` component is great; I like being able to access new events but, how do you add the opacity feedback the `TouchableOpacity` component has?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the answer of @Adams:

Here is the code, which worked for me. You can customize it.

```js
import { Pressable, Animated } from "react-native";
    
const animated = new Animated.Value(1);
const PressableOpacity = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const fadeIn = () => {
    Animated.timing(animated, {
      toValue: 0.1,
      duration: 100,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  };
  const fadeOut = () => {
    Animated.timing(animated, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 200,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  };
    
  return (
    <Pressable onPressIn={fadeIn} onPressOut={fadeOut} {...props}>
      <Animated.View style={{ opacity: animated }}>{children}</Animated.View>
    </Pressable>
  );
};
    
export default PressableOpacity;
```

Comment: FYI - I had to cut the `animated` variable above the `PressableOpacity` and paste it inside `PressableOpacity` or else the opacity animation would occur for all instances of `PressableOpacity` in the parent component

Answer (score 6):

There's a simple solution given here: https://medium.com/timeless/a-simple-touch-feedback-with-the-new-pressable-component-b4d91c35456

The `style` parameter of the `Pressable` component accepts function with `pressed` boolean which is very handy for this case.

I've made a simple cover component not to change the code:

```js
import { Pressable as PressableRaw } from 'react-native';

function Pressable(props) {
    return <PressableRaw
            onPress={props.onPress}
            hitSlop={props.hitSlop}
            style={({ pressed }) => [props.style || {}, {opacity:pressed ? 0.5 : 1}]}
            >{props.children}</PressableRaw>
}
```

Comment: This is by far the easiest solution that has more potential. Sadly the RN guys didn't implement this as a native feature, like they did with touchableOpacity.

Answer (score 4):

the best solution is to use `pressed` parameter of the `style` , such as :

```
<Pressable style=(({pressed}) => ({opacity: pressed ? 0.5 : 1}))>
</Pressable>
```

Comment: Is it possible to define additional styling for the Pressable component?

Comment: This works: style={({ pressed }) => [{ opacity: pressed ? 0.5 : 1.0 }, styles.defaultStyling]}

Answer (score 2):

You shoud use Animated API: https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated .
There is even an example with opacity.
You can also rewrite the example so that the button changes the opacity after "Press in" and returns to the default value after "Press Out"

Answer (score 0):

You can also use React Native ReAnimated 2 if you want a better version of @Andre's answer.

```
import Animated, {EasingNode} from 'react-native-reanimated';

const AnimatedView = Animated.View;
const animatedOpacity = new Animated.Value(1);

function fadeIn() {
  return Animated.timing(animatedOpacity, {
    toValue: 0.7,
    duration: 100,
    easing: EasingNode.inOut(EasingNode.ease),
  }).start();
}

function fadeOut() {
    return Animated.timing(animatedOpacity, {
    toValue: 1,
    duration: 120,
    easing: EasingNode.inOut(EasingNode.ease),
  }).start();
}

........
........

return(
    <Pressable
      onPressIn={fadeIn}
      onPressOut={fadeOut}
      onPress={() => console.log("Pressed !)}>
        <AnimatedView 
          style={[styles.button, {opacity: animatedOpacity}]}>
          <Text>Click Me!<Text>
        </AnimatedView>
    </Pressable>
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Typescript version with Expo haptics support and with a proper `forwardRef`.  This also forwards the existing event methods so that it can be extended past the animation.  One key point that is missing is the support for the `PressableStateCallback` for the `style` (it still allows it for the children) the typings on this one will guard against it.

This does the `Animated.createAnimatedComponent` to wrap the `Pressable` which allows for the `PressableStateCallback` for the `children`.

```js
import {
  PropsWithChildren,
  RefAttributes,
  forwardRef,
  useCallback,
  useRef,
} from "react";
import {
  Animated,
  GestureResponderEvent,
  Pressable,
  PressableProps,
  StyleProp,
  View,
  ViewStyle,
} from "react-native";
import * as Haptics from "expo-haptics";
/**
 * The props remove the functional `style` from the pressable to simplify this implementation.
 */
export type PressableOpacityProps = Omit<PressableProps, "style"> & {
  /**
   * Defaults to 0.2 (same as TouchableOpacity)
   */
  activeOpacity?: number;
  /**
   * If false, when long press is triggered, it will start the pressOut animation.
   * Defaults to false.
   */
  keepPressedOnLongPress?: boolean;
  /**
   * If false, haptics are disabled on long press.
   */
  disableHaptics?: boolean;
  /**
   * Defaults to 100ms
   */
  pressInAnimationDuration?: number;
  /**
   * Defaults to 200ms
   */
  pressOutAnimationDuration?: number;
  /**
   * Only allow the static style prop and not the functional one.
   */
  style: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
};
const AnimatedPressable = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Pressable);
const PressableOpacity = ({
  children,
  ref,
  activeOpacity = 0.2,
  pressInAnimationDuration = 100,
  pressOutAnimationDuration = 200,
  disableHaptics = false,
  keepPressedOnLongPress = false,
  onLongPress,
  onPressIn,
  onPressOut,
  style,
  ...props
}: RefAttributes<View> & PressableOpacityProps) => {
  const animation = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;
  const pressInEffect = useCallback(
    (event: GestureResponderEvent) => {
      Animated.timing(animation, {
        toValue: activeOpacity,
        duration: pressInAnimationDuration,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start();
      if (onPressIn) {
        onPressIn(event);
      }
    },
    [animation, onPressIn],
  );
  const pressOutEffect = useCallback(
    (event: GestureResponderEvent) => {
      Animated.timing(animation, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: pressOutAnimationDuration,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start();
      if (onPressOut) {
        onPressOut(event);
      }
    },
    [animation, onPressOut],
  );
  const longPressEffect = useCallback(
    (event: GestureResponderEvent) => {
      if (!keepPressedOnLongPress) {
        Animated.timing(animation, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: pressOutAnimationDuration,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start();
      }
      if (!disableHaptics) {
        Haptics.impactAsync(Haptics.ImpactFeedbackStyle.Medium);
      }
      if (onLongPress) {
        onLongPress(event);
      }
    },
    [onLongPress, disableHaptics, keepPressedOnLongPress],
  );
  return (
    <AnimatedPressable
      onPressIn={pressInEffect}
      onPressOut={pressOutEffect}
      onLongPress={longPressEffect}
      ref={ref}
      style={[style, { opacity: animation }]}
      {...props}
    >
      {children}
    </AnimatedPressable>
  );
};

export default forwardRef<View, PressableOpacityProps>((props, ref) => (
  <PressableOpacity {...props} ref={ref} />
));
```